# Uploading image using WebApi results in an invalid file on server

Tags: windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, image-uploading

I am unable to successfully upload a complete image file using WebApi.
One file upload actually results in two files being written to disk on the server when the controller's Post method is executed.

However, these files cannot be opened as the intended image files.
One file has 0 bytes and the other file has around 21kb.

I suspect that my client-side code is causing the issue.
So how can I successfully upload a complete image file using WebApi?

**Client Code:**

```
    internal async Task Upload(Windows.Storage.StorageFile file)
    {
        IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        var reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);

        var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", Globals.URL_PREFIX, "api/images");
        byte[] image = new byte[fileStream.Size];

        await UploadImage(image, url);
    }


    public async Task UploadImage(byte[] image, string url)
    {
        var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(image);
        imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");

        var fileName = string.Format("{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(imageContent, "image", fileName);

        Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(image);
        content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file", fileName);

        var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
        message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        message.Content = content;
        message.RequestUri = new Uri(url);

        var client = new HttpClient();

        await client.SendAsync(message).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //do something with response
            }
        });
    }
```

**Server Code:**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Profiles/");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    try 
    {
        // Read the form data.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue using azure blob storage. The issue for me was that I had to set the image source in the app to show the picture and could not do it from the computer. Maybe the question will help you even if it is not completely the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745377/uploading-image-to-azure-blob-storage

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Sadly, this did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Sorry Hopefully somebody else can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Client**:

```
 public async Task UploadImage(byte[] image, string url)
        {
            Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(image);
            HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());

            Uri resourceAddress = null;
            Uri.TryCreate(url.Trim(), UriKind.Absolute, out resourceAddress);
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Post, resourceAddress);
            request.Content = streamContent;

            var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(cts.Token);
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    Stream requestStream = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await requestStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
        byteArray = ms.ToArray();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this sample:
https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/FileUploadSample/ReadMe.txt

The issue I think is that you are trying to provide the same byte array twice. Where you really just need to do it once.

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(_filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, BufferSize, useAsync: true))
{
    // Create a stream content for the file
    StreamContent content = new StreamContent(fileStream, BufferSize);

    // Create Multipart form data content, add our submitter data and our stream content
    MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    formData.Add(new StringContent("Me"), "submitter");
    formData.Add(content, "filename", _filename);

    // Post the MIME multipart form data upload with the file
    Uri address = new Uri(_baseAddress + "api/fileupload");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(address, formData);

    FileResult result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<FileResult>();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}Result:{0}  Filename:  {1}{0}  Submitter: {2}", Environment.NewLine, result.FileNames.FirstOrDefault(), result.Submitter);
}
```

Comment: I need an answer to be compliant with Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: Use the stream you got in your sample instead of the filestream?